# Interval nonvariant under Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity

How do I show that physical quantities don't change after Lorentz transformations?

Comment: Please do not remove the [tag:homework-and-exercises] tag, but [read our homework policy instead](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583).

Comment: A Lorentz transformation is *defined* to be one that leaves $ds^2$ invariant.

Comment: @Barry_Allen:  Can you show that every bachelor is really unmarried?

Comment: Consider a Lorentz transformation along an axis, let's say the x-axis. Write down t' and x' in terms of t and x (y' and z' will be invariant, i.e. equal to y and z respectively). Then you can get dx' and dt'. Use the fact that $ds'^2=-dt'^2+dx'^2+dy'^2+dz'^2$. You must check that this is equal to $ds^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Lorentz transformation along an axis, let's say the x-axis. There's no loss of generality by doing so.

Write down t' and x' in terms of t and x (y' and z' will be invariant, i.e. equal to y and z respectively). Then you can get dx' and dt'. Use the fact that $ds'^2=-dt'^2+dx'^2+dy'^2+dz'^2$. You must check that this is equal to $ds^2$.

See [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Boost_in_the_x-direction) for an expression fo the primed coordinates.

Comment: Start with the fact that $ds'^2=-dt'^2+dx'^2+dy'^2+dz'^2$. Replace the primed quantities on the right hand-side in terms of non primed quantities.